# Redis queue used by various services ( create a lock to )

Tags: java, spring-boot, queue, redisson

I'm using the [Reddison](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) client in a Java Spring Boot application.

I need to re-use a value (it's just a string) among all the members of the service. I'm thinking of using a Queue. When a service stops using the value, it puts it back in the queue, when a new service needs a value it takes it from the queue.

I'm trying to figure out how to read the value without several nodes pick up the same one. I don't couldn't find a way to create a lock and then release it.

I'm trying the following:

```java
// When done using the value: 
Queue<String> q = redis.getQueue(KEY);
q.offer(value);
//when need a value;
Queue<String> q = redis.getQueue(KEY);
q.poll();
```

But this code runs on all the nodes, so, how can I guarantee 10 of them don't get the same value when I call `poll`

I see the client has a `redis.createTransaction(options)`  method that could return a transaction but it doesn't allow to get a queue.

Comment: You don't need to create any lock or transaction. Both offer and poll are atomic calls to the Redis server. You will never get the same value (assuming the values are unique).

Comment: @Mar-Z  How  do two different JVM's synchronize to avoid reading exactly the same value? Is there something that happens automatically at the Redis level?

Comment: Yes it happens at Redis server. RQueue object you get from redis.getQueue(KEY) is a distributed and concurrent implementation of Java Queue backed by Redis. Redis serves the requests from clients as FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I can acquire a lock with [8. Distributed locks and synchronizers](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/8.-distributed-locks-and-synchronizers)

```java
RLock lock = redisson.getLock("myLock");

// traditional lock method
lock.lock();

// or acquire lock and automatically unlock it after 10 seconds
lock.lock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// or wait for lock aquisition up to 100 seconds 
// and automatically unlock it after 10 seconds
boolean res = lock.tryLock(100, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (res) {
   try {
     ...
   } finally {
       lock.unlock();
   }
}
```

But now I wonder if I have to do it? @Mar-Z mentions they are not needed, but I can't find a reference to confirm it, but this is the answer to my question (how to get a lock)